# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}= 1$

Tags: limits

Prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)} = 1$$

I already know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = 1$, but now sure how to use it.

Comment: Observe that $\log$ is a continuous function and hence the limit sign can be taken inside the log.

Comment: If you know the behaviour of $\sqrt[n]{n}$, use $1\leqslant\ln(n+1)\leqslant n$ hence $$1\leqslant\sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}\leqslant\sqrt[n]{n}.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint : $1\le\ln(n+1) \le n$ then use what you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the theorem that when $a_n\to L$ then $\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdots a_n} \to L$ with $a_n=\frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n) = \sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}$, and let $g(n) = \ln f(n) = \frac{1}{n}\ln(\ln(n+1))$.
By L'Hôpital, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\frac{1}{n+1}=0.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = 1$$
by continuity of $\ln$.

Answer (score 0):

Let y=$\sqrt[n]{\ln(n+1)}$

Take the natural log of both sides,
$\implies ln(y)=\frac{ln(ln(n+1))}{n}$
Now either you can apply L.H rule, or simply see that n increases much faster than ln(ln(n+1)),
So for n$\rightarrow \infty$ ln(y)=0, yielding y=1.